# Run emulator on jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator

i am trying to run emulator on jenkins but whenever i run following command

```
  emulator/emulator -skin 1080x1920 -ports 5784,5785 -report-console tcp:5868,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd emulatorname -wipe-data -no-window
```

i am getting following error

ERROR   | could not connect to server on TCP:5868: Operation timed out
saving arm snapshot.... !!!

```
INFO    | Wait for emulator (pid 99639) 20 seconds to shutdown gracefully before kill;you can set environment variable ANDROID_EMULATOR_WAIT_TIME_BEFORE_KILL(in seconds) to change the default value (20 seconds)
```

Can  someone help with script which will open the emulator and wait till its finish boot